# How to profile a MSpec test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, profiler, mspec

I've run dotTrace and Visual Studio profiler against a MSpec test, but so far I haven't been able to get any information about the code that is being tested, only about the code of the test itself.

Is there a way to do this?

My guess is using lambdas for the Because clause may be the reason why the actual tested code doesn't show up.

Comment: What profiling method do you use (sampling, tracing or line-by-line)?